# Задать контролу цвет выбранный пользователем

Tags: c#, wpf, color, label

В WPF хотел реализовать выбор цвета для `Label` но столкнулся с такой проблемой: 
хотел использовать класс `ColorDialog` из `WindowsForms` но там привести так просто не получится. Как можно было бы задать Label из WPF цвет, выбранный пользователем, другими вариантами или как нужно исправить мой вариант, чтобы он работал. И было бы не плохо не сразу задать цвет, а вынести её в переменную типа `Brushes или Brush`. Вот код:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog();
dialog.ShowDialog();
NewPlayerName.Visibility = AddPlayerButton.Visibility = (sender as Button).Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
myLabel.Foreground = Color.FromArgb(dialog.Color.A,dialog.Color.R,dialog.Color.G,dialog.Color.G, dialog.Color.B);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы не проверяете результат ShowDialog. Если пользователь нажал отмену, свойство Color не определено.
2. Свойство Label.Foreground принимает Brush, а не Color.
3. Аргументы Color.FromArgb у вас неверные.

Правильно так:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog();
var dres = dialog.ShowDialog();

if (dres != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    myLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(
        Color.FromArgb(dialog.Color.A, dialog.Color.R, dialog.Color.G, dialog.Color.B)
        );

}
```